# Make fixed position div scrollable without scrollbar and without scrolling the background content

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, fixed

In a website I'm developing I have a div that's used for the main menu in the mobile version.

That div is fixed (css below) but in some cases it's height is greater than the device's height.

I want to style the div to have `max-height: 100%` but, if the content overflows the device's height, I need it to be scrollable without scrollbar and without moving the rest of the website.

CSS:

```
.mobile_menu 
{
    display: none; /*toggled onclick*/
    position: fixed;
    right: 0; 
    top: 86px; /*standard value. calculated after via javascript shown below*/
    z-index: 9;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('.mobile_menu').css("top", $("#header_left").height());
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mobile_menu" style="top: 63px; display: block;">
    <ul>
        <li data-element="1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <span>a</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li data-element="2">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <span>b</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li data-element="3">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <span>c</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there any what that I can achieve what I pretend?

Comment: Can you provide a live example or a Fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ugly but it works

```
.mobile_menu 
{
    //...
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    right: -25px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sk9dhgbj/

Answer (score 0):

Delete this:

```
style="top: 63px; display: block;" in your HTML
```

Comment: It's generated by Javascript.

Comment: It's generated by Javascript, as said above.

Display toggles between block and none. Top is calculated according header's height.